# Cordova, Xcode build: Interface Builder Cocoa touch Error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cocoa, hybrid-mobile-app

while not being able to make a proper **build on iOS of a Cordova app**, I started to view the **system.log on mac**, what I found out is that during the build and while I run the project on Xcode I get the following error which I have never seen before and do not event know what its all about.

[image: Error Cocoa Builder]

What I get after this build is just a white page.

Do you have any idea on what this is or how to troubleshoot in this case?

What is *interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool*?

What is *IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool*? Where do they come from?

I already searched on stackoverflow but could not find a proper solution for my issue.

I am only running the app on simulator not on a device.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

***EDIT***: Actually, as Jeremy mentioned below, this is not a problem.

But my guesses are that maybe the Xcode version is the culprit, this application was **developed in Xcode 6.0, but I am trying to run it with Xcode 9**, may this be a **compatibility** **issue** between versions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool is the tool that is run by Xcode to produce compiled nibs from your xibs.

IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool is the tool that is run by Xcode to produce your asset catalogs.

Those messages are benign and just result from the way those tools are run (without a bootstrap port).